# Content-length available in Curl, Wget, but not in Python Requests

Tags: python, http, curl, wget

I have an URL pointing to a binary file which I need to download after checking its size, because the download should only be (re-)executed if the local file size differs from the remote file size.

This is how it works with `wget` (anonymized host names and IPs):

```
$ wget <URL>
--2020-02-17 11:09:18--  <URL>
Resolving <URL> (<host>)... <IP>
Connecting to <host> (<host>)|<ip>|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 31581872 (30M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘[...]’
```

This also works fine with the `--continue` flag in order to resume a download, including skipping if the file was completely downloaded earlier.

I can do the same with `curl`, the `content-length` is also present:

```
$ curl -I <url>
HTTP/2 200 
date: Mon, 17 Feb 2020 13:11:55 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000
last-modified: Fri, 14 Feb 2020 15:42:29 GMT
etag: "[...]"
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 31581872
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-type: application/x-gzip
```

In Python, I try to implement the same logic by checking the `Content-length` header using the [requests library](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
        with requests.get(url, stream=True) as response:
            total_size = int(response.headers.get("Content-length"))

            if not response.ok:
                logger.error(
                    f"Error {response.status_code} when downloading file from {url}"
                )
            elif os.path.exists(file) and os.stat(file).st_size == total_size:
                logger.info(f"File '{file}' already exists, skipping download.")
            else:
                [...] # download file
```

It turns out that the `Content-length` header is never present, i.e. gets a `None` value here. I know that this should be worked around by passing a default value to the `get()` call, but for the purpose of debugging, this example consequently triggers an exception:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

I can confirm manually that the `Content-length` header is not there:

```
requests.get(url, stream=True).headers
{'Date': '[...]', 'Server': '[...]', 'Strict-Transport-Security': '[...]', 'Upgrade': '[...]', 'Connection': 'Upgrade, Keep-Alive', 'Last-Modified': '[...]', 'ETag': ''[...]'', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=15, max=100', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-gzip'}
```

This logic works fine though for other URLs, i.e. I do get the `Content-length` header.

When using `requests.head(url)` (omitting the `stream=True`), I get the same headers except for `Transfer-Encoding`.

I understand that a server does not have to send a `Content-length` header.
However, `wget` and `curl` clearly do get that header. What do they do differently from my Python implementation?

Comment: Further investigation: this does _not_ seem related to the `Transfer-Encoding` header because when using `requests.head()`, the problem persists (added to question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer to the question about the missing `Content-length` header, but a solution to the underlying problem:

Instead of checking the local file size vs the content length of the remote, I have ended up checking the `Last-modified` header and compare that to the `mtime` of the local file. This is also safer in (the unlikely) case that the remote file is updated, but still has the exact same size.